# Variable Name from Memory address in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

My c++ application developed in Visual Studio 2008 crashes at some memory location. It is showing memory access violation erroe  like,
Unhandled exception at 0x650514aa in XXX.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.

how I can get the variable name assigned to 0x650514aa this memory location. Or how to debug this issue.

Thanks,
Nilesh

Answer (score 4):

`0x650514aa` is the address of code (instruction pointer), not of a variable. If you're lucky, it's your code. Then a map file would help. If you're unlucky, it's some third-party code (blowing because you called it passing in nonsense). But it ain't pretty to dig through map files and it won't tell you your variables' values anyway.

However, if you run it from the debugger, the debugger should intercept and let you examine the stack. And even if you run it without debugger, just-in-time debugging should pop up a dialog asking whether you want to attach a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers here have useful information. But if for some reason you cannot get the debugger to assist you, here's some more detail you can get out of that error message that may help you locate the problem.

> Access violation reading location 0x00000004.

That memory location is what the program is incorrectly trying to read. Typically, reading or writing to a very low memory location like that is caused by code trying to use a NULL pointer as if it pointed to a valid object.

If you happen to know roughly what part of your program is executing when this error occurs, then examine it for any possibilities for NULL pointers to slip through unexpectedly.

Furthermore, 0x00000004 would be the location of a member variable 4 bytes from the start of the object. If the object has virtual functions, then it would probably be the first member variable in the object (because those first 4 bytes are the hidden pointer to the virtual function table). Otherwise, without virtual functions involved, there must be 4 bytes worth of other member variables and/or padding bytes before it. So if you can't immediately tell which pointer is going NULL and causing the problem, then consider which pointers are being used to read such a member variable.

(Note: Technically, the exact memory layout of non-POD objects, particularly when virtual functions are involved, is not guaranteed by any standard. Byte alignment settings in your project can also affect memory layouts. However, in this case it's fairly safe to assume that what I've described is what your compiler is actually doing.)

Comment: Are you sure reading 0x00000004 is reading from the start of an object, and not from the start of the process's virtual memory?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if you debug your application inside Visual Studio 2008, at the time of the crash it will stop right at the offending line. Be sure to compile in the Debug configuration, then click **Debug | Start**.

For further checking, you can go to **Debug | Exceptions** and check the boxes "Break when an exception is thrown".

Answer (score 0):

If you're running in debug, you should be able to have the system break at that point and be able to see the source code.

If you're running in release mode however, you may need to use the .map file that can be generated. (Link switch /MAP, and you'll need to specify the export files too)

There's a description of how to for v6 here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/mapfile.aspx

2008 is pretty similar, I believe, although I tend to prefer to run in debug mode if possible.

The map file will allow you to translate your crash address into an exact location in the source code (line number), which may well be helpful. However it will only tell you where the error manifested - not what actually caused it (e.g. a stack corruption wouldn't tell you when you corrupted the stack, only when the corrupted stack was discovered.)

Still, it should help point you in the right direction.